# Pass cookie to JSON request

Tags: javascript, json, cookies

I'm logged into a secure website with a login. There is data on the page that I want that is passed through the server with JSON data. When I open Chrome then Inspect and look at the "Network" tab I see a URL using XHR and when I click on the preview tab I see the JSON data that I am looking for. When I open the same URL in another tab I get the JSON response:

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Invalid cookie value"}
```

I can see the data in the inspect tool but if I try to load the exact URL even within the same browser session I get the error. I understand that when the request is made there is a cookie attached to it so that the response from the secure server is valid. Is there a way to get around this or somehow take the session cookie that is valid and push it to the server so that I can get the raw JSON response in a URL?

My ultimate goal is to parse the JSON data using Tampermokey.

Comment: some code would help, to see what and how you are sending using XHR

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm the end user viewing the data on the website. I'm not the actual code/server making the request

Comment: right ... I see how I got confused

Comment: When you put a url into your address bar, your browser makes a `GET` request. The app might be sending a `POST` instead.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey I believe you're right. Is there a way to mimic a post request and still get access to the JSON data?

Comment: Use postman or any http debugging tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way for a user to set cookies in browser requests, especially if you're doing it through the address bar. There are a lot of tools than can do this, though. Personally I use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to send requests, with another tool by them called [Interceptor](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/02/11/postman-v0-9-6-access-cookies-and-restricted-headers-plus-better-testing/) for setting stuff like cookies.